# cordova error building project: Android resource linking failed

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to build the cordova android project and thats what I got:

```
> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed

cordova/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:2548: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.
```

The project was used to work, this just happened from no where. Tried to remove the android platform and reinstall and got more and more issues.

**UPDATE**

Now I got this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.intentfilter:android-permissions:0.1.8.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/intentfilter/android-permissions/0.1.8/android-permissions-0.1.8.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/intentfilter/android-permissions/0.1.8/android-permissions-0.1.8.pom
       - .../cordova/platforms/android/app/libs/com/intentfilter/android-permissions/0.1.8/android-permissions-0.1.8.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
```

Comment: run command `ionic cordova resources android`.

Comment: im not using ionic

Comment: just use `cordova resources android`

Comment: Cordova does not know resources; try `cordova help` for a list of all the available commands.

Comment: Paste values.xml

Comment: I have deleted my cordova android platform, deleted the whole android studio, removed any plugin from my cordova xml file. Installed everything one by one until it resolved. it took just 6 hours in total. I think that google should pay me about this.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't related to any of that, because the ignored error message reads:

> Could not find `com.intentfilter:android-permissions:0.1.8`.

Add `mavenCentral()` as repository, in order to let Gradle download the AAR:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.intentfilter/android-permissions/0.1.8

Comment: My build has mavenCentral(), but its trying to pull from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/intentfilter/android-permissions/0.1.8/android-permissions-0.1.8.pom when the actual URL appears to be https://mvnrepository.com/ Any idea how to update that?

Answer (score -1):

Check npm version. Apart from additional errors, I had the same situation. Try to upgrade npm to latest major release.

If You have lockfile v1 instead of v2, I am 99% sure it's this.

FYI it happened to me just now. I have installed docker (another project), then went back to build the app and I had the same, original error. Also I have tried to re-add node_modules/ and cordova platform. Didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error and the only way I could fix it was removing and re-adding some cordova plugins. I'm not sure which of them was causing it (because more then one were updated), but the problem is solved.